# Android crash because of ACodec

Tags: android

I have seen a lot of Android cash reports in 2021 in Google Play Console, the crash is thrown from libstagefright.so library, it's native code, I have no way to find from where or which activiy they are throwing.

Here is the stack trace:

> backtrace:
> #00  pc 00000000000b24a4  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::DataConverter::convert(android::spandroid::MediaCodecBuffer const&, android::spandroid::MediaCodecBuffer&)+27)
> #00  pc 000000000009d14b  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::ACodec::BaseState::onOMXFillBufferDone(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, long long, int)+594)
> #00  pc 000000000009ca8f  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::ACodec::BaseState::onOMXMessage(android::spandroid::AMessage const&)+274)
> #00  pc 000000000000fc0b  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::AHierarchicalStateMachine::handleMessage(android::spandroid::AMessage const&)+58)
> #00  pc 000000000009c887  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::ACodec::BaseState::onOMXMessageList(android::spandroid::AMessage const&)+106)
> #00  pc 000000000009c4e1  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::ACodec::BaseState::onMessageReceived(android::spandroid::AMessage const&)+460)
> #00  pc 000000000000fc0b  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::AHierarchicalStateMachine::handleMessage(android::spandroid::AMessage const&)+58)
> #00  pc 000000000000fa85  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::AHandler::deliverMessage(android::spandroid::AMessage const&)+24)
> #00  pc 0000000000011f91  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::AMessage::deliver()+60)
> #00  pc 00000000000106eb  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::ALooper::loop()+470)
> #00  pc 000000000000d32b  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+270)
> #00  pc 000000000006e919  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+80)
> #00  pc 0000000000047ba3  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+22)
> #00  pc 000000000001b067  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)

Comment: facing same any solution?

Comment: Hi no idea for now.